Giving error on scrolling down and Giving error , "LOAD MORE" button not found or not able to click on that
I was attempting to fetch a list of 100 shirts from the Allen Solly website. So, I added logic for the 'Load More' button because only 30 to 32 products were displayed at the time of site loading. However, when clicking on the 'Load More' button, it showed an error stating that the item 'could not be scrolled into view'.

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-outlined MuiButton-outlinedSecondaryblack MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-outlinedSizeMedium MuiButton-root MuiButton-outlined MuiButton-outlinedSecondaryblack MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-outlinedSizeMedium css-gfqi95" type="button"> could not be scrolled into view


Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:193:5
ElementNotInteractableError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:353:5
webdriverClickElement@chrome://remote/content/marionette/interaction.sys.mjs:166:11
interaction.clickElement@chrome://remote/content/marionette/interaction.sys.mjs:135:11
clickElement@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsChild.sys.mjs:204:29
receiveMessage@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsChild.sys.mjs:84:31

Code
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

# Set up the Selenium WebDriver for Firefox
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

try:
    # Navigate to the main shirts page
    url = 'https://allensolly.abfrl.in/c/men-shirts'
    driver.get(url)

    # Wait for the page to load completely
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'ProductCard_productInfo__uZhFN')))

    # Ensure we have at least 100 shirts by clicking the "LOAD MORE" button if needed
    product_info = []
    while len(product_info) < 100:
        # Scroll down to load more products
        last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        while True:
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            time.sleep(5)  # Wait for new products to load

            # Click the "LOAD MORE" button
            load_more_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/main/div/div[7]/div/div[2]/button')))
            load_more_button.click()
            print("Clicked 'LOAD MORE' button.")
            
            # Wait for new content to load
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.staleness_of(load_more_button))

            new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
            if new_height == last_height:
                break
            last_height = new_height

        # Get the updated page source
        page_source = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')

        # Find all elements with the product title class and add to the list
        products = soup.find_all('div', class_='ProductCard_productInfo__uZhFN')
        for product in products:
            title_element = product.find('div', class_='ProductCard_title__9M6wy')
            detail_element = product.find('div', class_='ProductCard_description__BQzle')  # Assuming this class holds details
            if title_element and detail_element:
                title = title_element.text.strip()
                detail = detail_element.text.strip()
                product_info.append((title, detail))

        # If we have reached 100 unique products, break the loop
        if len(product_info) >= 100:
            break

    # Print the number of unique products found
    print(f"Number of unique products found: {len(product_info)}")

    # Click on each product detail to open it in a new tab
    data = []  # List to store scraped data
    for idx, (title, detail) in enumerate(product_info[:100], start=1):
        print(f"{idx}. Title: {title}\n   Product: {detail}\n")
        try:
            # Find the product description element using the product title
            description_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f'//div[contains(@class, "ProductCard_title__9M6wy") and contains(text(), "{title}")]/ancestor::div[contains(@class, "ProductCard_productInfo__uZhFN")]'))
            )

            # Scroll the element into view and click it using JavaScript
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", description_element)
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", description_element)
            print("Opened product description.")
            
            # Wait for the new tab to open
            time.sleep(2)

            # Switch to the new tab
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
            print("Switched to new tab.")

            # Scraping the product description from the new tab using CSS selector
            product_description_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#__next > main > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.col-sm-5.col-md-5.col-lg-5 > div > div.PDPDetails_prodDescDetails__D7ddV > div.ProductDetails_container__0vRlj.ProductDetails_AS__WcrW_ > p.MuiTypography-root.MuiTypography-body1.ProductDetails_description__7hqm9.css-12a9y8i'))
            )
            product_description = product_description_element.text.strip()

            # Append scraped data to the list
            data.append(('Allen Solly', 'Men', title, detail, product_description))
            print(product_description)
            
            # Close the new tab
            driver.close()
            print("Closed new tab.")

            # Switch back to the original tab
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
            print("Switched back to the original tab.")

            # Wait for the page to reload
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f'//div[contains(@class, "ProductCard_title__9M6wy") and contains(text(), "{title}")]'))
            )
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error occurred while processing product detail: {str(e)}")

    # Convert the scraped data into a pandas DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Brand', 'Category', 'Title', 'Product Detail', 'Product Description'])

    # Export the DataFrame to an Excel file
    df.to_excel('scraped_data.xlsx', index=False)

finally:
    driver.quit()



have you checked this? also, it would be easier and faster to scrape the api endpoint instead of using selenium

I rewrote much of the beginning of the script.

I removed the try-except because it just hides errors. You need to see when something goes wrong so you can fix it. Once everything is working perfectly, then add try-except only to catch specific exceptions and only if you are going to handle them.

I removed the time.sleep(), they are not a good practice. I replaced them with WebDriverWait.

I changed the processing of LOAD MORE buttons. I added a variable, max_pages, that tracks the number of pages to load. Each page contains 32 products.

I changed the page scrolling method because it was scrolling the entire page all at once which doesn't load each product. You need to scroll one page at a time to force all products to load.


I tested the portion of the code that I rewrote and verified that 96 products were obtained. I stopped when you started opening new tabs.
The updated code.
import time
import pandas as pd

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# Set up the Selenium WebDriver for Firefox
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

# Navigate to the main shirts page
url = 'https://allensolly.abfrl.in/c/men-shirts'
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# wait for the popup to appear and close
popup_root = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ct-web-popup-imageonly"))).shadow_root
close_button = popup_root.find_element(By.ID, "close")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", close_button)

# click LOAD MORE
load_more = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='LOAD MORE']")))
print(f"first len(load_more): {len(load_more)}")
count = 1
max_pages = 3 # each page contains 32 products
while load_more and count < max_pages:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", load_more[0])
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.loader-wrapper")))
    wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.loader-wrapper")))
    load_more = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='LOAD MORE']")))
    count += 1

# scroll page by page to the bottom
current_position = driver.execute_script("return window.scrollY + window.innerHeight")
height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.clientHeight")
while current_position < height:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);")
    current_position = driver.execute_script("return window.scrollY + window.innerHeight")
    time.sleep(0.5)

product_info = []
# Get the updated page source
page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')

# Find all elements with the product title class and add to the list
products = soup.find_all('div', class_='ProductCard_productInfo__uZhFN')
for product in products:
    title_element = product.find('div', class_='ProductCard_title__9M6wy')
    detail_element = product.find('div', class_='ProductCard_description__BQzle')  # Assuming this class holds details
    if title_element and detail_element:
        title = title_element.text.strip()
        detail = detail_element.text.strip()
        product_info.append((title, detail))

# Print the number of unique products found
print(f"Number of unique products found: {len(product_info)}")

# Click on each product detail to open it in a new tab
data = []  # List to store scraped data
for idx, (title, detail) in enumerate(product_info[:100], start=1):
    print(f"{idx}. Title: {title}\n   Product: {detail}\n")
    try:
        # Find the product description element using the product title
        description_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f'//div[contains(@class, "ProductCard_title__9M6wy") and contains(text(), "{title}")]/ancestor::div[contains(@class, "ProductCard_productInfo__uZhFN")]'))
        )

        # Scroll the element into view and click it using JavaScript
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", description_element)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", description_element)
        print("Opened product description.")
        
        # Wait for the new tab to open
        time.sleep(2)

        # Switch to the new tab
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
        print("Switched to new tab.")

        # Scraping the product description from the new tab using CSS selector
        product_description_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#__next > main > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.col-sm-5.col-md-5.col-lg-5 > div > div.PDPDetails_prodDescDetails__D7ddV > div.ProductDetails_container__0vRlj.ProductDetails_AS__WcrW_ > p.MuiTypography-root.MuiTypography-body1.ProductDetails_description__7hqm9.css-12a9y8i'))
        )
        product_description = product_description_element.text.strip()

        # Append scraped data to the list
        data.append(('Allen Solly', 'Men', title, detail, product_description))
        print(product_description)
        
        # Close the new tab
        driver.close()
        print("Closed new tab.")

        # Switch back to the original tab
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
        print("Switched back to the original tab.")

        # Wait for the page to reload
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f'//div[contains(@class, "ProductCard_title__9M6wy") and contains(text(), "{title}")]'))
        )
    except Exception as close_button:
        print(f"Error occurred while processing product detail: {str(close_button)}")

# Convert the scraped data into a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Brand', 'Category', 'Title', 'Product Detail', 'Product Description'])

# Export the DataFrame to an Excel file
df.to_excel('scraped_data.xlsx', index=False)

driver.quit()

